# PL/SQL Functions in oracle EBS

Tags: oracle

Hi I am fairly new to oracle Ebs..I came upon a pl/sql function which is checking a variable in the iprocurement is with the specified list or not.. I am not sure about how the `SELECT 'Y'` is written.

```
function if_it (header_id NUMBER) RETURN CHAR IS

  x_it CHAR(1);
begin

SELECT DISTINCT if_it
into x_it 
FROM ( 
SELECT 'Y' if_it
FROM po.po_requisition_lines pr
where nvl(to_number(pr.attribute1), 0) IN (1,2,3) 
and pr.requisition_header_id = header_id
UNION 
SELECT 'N' is_it FROM DUAL);

return x_it;

exception when others then -- returned Yes and No, so we want to retyurn Yes
    return 'Y';
end if_it;
```

Comment: Could you clarify what is the question here? Perhaps one possibility here is to modify the query to `count(*)` one and return Y/N depending on (count > 1).

Comment: what does the 'SELECT 'Y' if_it' line do i.e. how does the inner select work..

Answer (score 0):

You are aliasing 'Y' as `if_it` when the row of data `pr.attribute1` is equal to 1,2 or 3.  And the `pr.requisition_header_id = header_id`.  So anytime those two things are true in the `po.po_requisition_lines pr` table you are selecting a hard-coded value of 'Y'. Then you select 'N' and alias it as `is_it`. So if the `header_id` you are passing in does not match a `pr.requisition_header_id` from the `po.po_requisition_lines pr` table your `Select Distinct` will only return 'N'.  If your `header_id` does match you will get back a 'Y' and 'N'.

Comment: HI Ryan,thanks for the quick reply. I could understand the portion till Union, but after that not sure what you meant by saying the the header_id not matching part. Also UNION 
SELECT 'N' is_it FROM DUAL ---  UNION 
SELECT 'N' if_it FROM DUAL instead

Comment: OK Ryan, I think I got it. Thanks

Comment: Union combines the two select statements (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). Selecting from 'N' from dual will always give a result, adn the result with always be 'N' with the code you have supplied.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns 'N' if and only if none of the records in po.po_requisition_lines where attribute1 is in (1, 2, 3) has requisition_header_id equal to the given parameter header_id. The definition is a bit overcomplicated (can be simpler).

The whole select returns either:

```
N
```

or

```
Y
N
```

But the latter will raise an exception because there is `into` clause (which expects single row returned only).

The inner select: similar, just may have several records with Y. (The outer select removes duplicates using `distinct` clause).

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
function if_it (p_header_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
begin
FOR cur IN (SELECT NULL FROM DUAL
              WHERE EXISTS 
              (SELECT NULL
                FROM po.po_requisition_lines pr
                where nvl(to_number(pr.attribute1), 0) IN (1,2,3) 
                and pr.requisition_header_id = p_header_id)
            ) LOOP
  RETURN 'Y';
END LOOP;
RETURN 'N'; 

end if_it;
```